# Can i predict how many swaps a algorithm will do knowing how an array was shuffled?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, swap, shuffle

I need to take a *snapshot* of an array **each N times two elements gets swapped** by a user-defined sorting algorithm. This **N dipends by the total number of swaps M** which the algorithm will perform once the array is ordered.

The size of the array can get up millions of elements, so I realized that running the algorithm two times (one for counting M, and one for taking these *snapshots*) gets too long on time when working with slow algorithm like BubbleSort.

Since I am the one who shuffle this algorithm I was wondering: is there a way to know how many swaps (or at least **a superior limit of it**) a precise sorting algorithm will do?

N is defined like:

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: For bubble sort specifically you can count inversions. But for general sorting algorithms, you're going to run afoul of Rice's theorem pretty quickly.

Comment: Another possibility would be to take more snapshots than you need and delete every other snapshot when too many accumulate. But this assumes that you can settle for an N' within a factor of two of N.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @DavidEisenstat. It would be nice to do that, but how can i quantify the 'more', without knowing the total number of swaps? 
Unfortunately, I can't afford to take a snapshot every single swap, because the snapshot is a file (which take space, approx. 100-1000 KB and time for writing).

Comment: You don't need to snapshot after every swap. I can post an answer if N is an increasing function of the swap count and some imprecision in N is acceptable.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, you're right. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to modify the object class you are working with? You could try to pass a user-defined array class which owns a counter. Using operator overloading you could modify the assigment operator and increment the counter everytime
`myarray[i]= newvalue`
is called.

Comment: I think you didn't get the actual question. What you wrote would just result in counting all the swaps done by an algorithm, am I wrong?

Comment: (@MattiaMonari: well, looks good for determining M, and as you don't know N beforehand, call it the first half of a solution.)

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I assumed that you already fixed N beforehand because (as @David-Eisenstat already pointed out) knowing M exactly in advance is difficult. This depends on the input array and the specific implementation of the sorting algorithm.


I don' t think that the problem "Given a specific sorting algorithm and a syntactically correct input, determine the number of swap operation used" is undecidable as you can simply execute the program.
To run a BubbleSort on large arrays even once should be a major problem, this could be worth reconsidering

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Watermelon. As i said in the question, i just need a good estimation of M, it doesn't have to be perfect. I took Bubble Sort as an example, but the problems applies to other n^2  (average) complexity algorithm (e.g. Insertion Sort). It would be useful to have some kind of formula which provide at least a superior limit for M.